# Using Cocos2d i need to set a sprite boundaries so it cant go off screen, how do I do this?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, boundary

im using cocos2d to create a game and i want to set my sprite a boundary so that it cannot go off the screen on the line of x. What code can i use to do this. I dont want the sprite to be bounced back in the opposite direction i just want it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12 explains how to set boundaries.

Shamelessly pasted code follows:

```
// Create edges around the entire screen
b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0); 
_groundBody = _world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
b2PolygonShape groundBox;
b2FixtureDef groundBoxDef;
groundBoxDef.shape = &groundBox;
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
_bottomFixture = _groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);
```

The last line setAsEdge sets the edge :D

However, if you want no bouncing, you can eiter set your moving sprite to

```
spriteDef.restitution = 0f;
```

or d that on the edge itself, depending if your moving sprite has to bounce on other stuff or not.